# Следущаяя и предыдущая новость php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую, есть одна новость.
метод модели вытаскивает по id одну новость,
как реализовать на этой же странице ссылки на следующую новость и предыдущую.
И чтобы выводились название след.и предыд. новости.

Answer (score 0):

Если порядок новостей у Вас задается при помощи `id` то так

```sql
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id < 333 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id >= 333 ORDER BY id LIMIT 2;
```

Или вот так

```sql
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id < 333 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = 333
UNION
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > 333 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Разница между  первым и вторым вариантами в результате при отсутствии новости с указанным `id`.

Первый вариант будет работать быстрее